# Intuit IPP AggCat - UNAVAILABLE NotRefreshedReason when calling getAccountTransactions

Tags: intuit-partner-platform

When calling getAccountTransactions to retrieve account transactions, I get a UNAVAILABLE NotRefreshedReason on some accounts.

Accounts used with getAccountTransactions have a correct account type (not other).

What do we need to do in case of UNAVAILABLE NotRefreshedReason ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I contact Intuit support and after few exchanges with them, they tell me a way to retrieve the intuit error code associated with UNAVAILABLE NotRefreshedReason.

It is possible to retrieve Intuit error code in field aggrStatusCode when calling getCustomerAccounts, getAccount or getLoginAccounts.

You can then check error codes on this link : https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0020_customeraccountdata/customer_account_data_api/0700_error_codes

Some error codes can be managed with your application users, but other may need account deletion or to contact Intuit support.